# Add seconds to predefined date in PHP

Tags: php

I want to add 20 seconds to this date: `"2017-08-31T23:59:59+02:00"`. Ive tried this:

```
// add 20s to orderDate
$s = 20;
$oldDate = $order->effectiveDate;
$date = new DateTime($oldDate);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$s.'S'));
$effectiveDate = date("Y-m-d", $date);

// store new date
$index['effectiveDate'] = $effectiveDate;
```

But `$effectiveDate` is false. I think it has something to do with DateTime to date conversion?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: `$effectiveDate = date("Y-m-d", $date);`.. here is catch..

Comment: @JonStirling. So simple, how could I have missed it.. Thanks!

Comment: If it is false, it failed to extract the time from the given format. While Datetime is very flexible I always seem to prefer converting it to a Unix timestamp. Avoids issues like this.